# eclipse indigo crashes very often when using ANTLR 3

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, antlr, antlr3

I am working on an ANTLR project. Here are the software details:
Eclipse - Indigo (3.7.2 SP2)
ANTLR IDE - 2.1.2
Derived Languages Toolkit - 3.0.0
GEF - 3.7.2
ZEST - 1.3.0
OS - UBUNTU 14.04

eclipse crashes very often and it is hardly of any use. Below are the info i see on the terminal when eclipse crashes

> No bp log location saved, using default.
>   [000:000] Cpu: 6.60.3, x4, 2400Mhz, 3711MB
>
> [000:000] Computer model: Not available
>
> [000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
>
> [000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
>
> [000:000] Using Gtk2 toolkit No bp log location saved, using default.
>
> [000:000] Cpu: 6.60.3, x4, 2400Mhz, 3711MB
>
> [000:000] Computer model: Not available
>
> [000:003] Warning(optionsfile.cc:30): Load: Could not open file, err=2
>
> [000:003] No bp log location saved, using default.
>
> [000:003] Cpu: 6.60.3, x4, 2400Mhz, 3711MB
>
> [000:003] Computer model: Not available
>
> [000:003] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
>
> [000:003] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
>
> [000:003] Using Gtk2 toolkit
>
> [000:002] Warning(optionsfile.cc:30): Load: Could not open file, err=2
>
> [000:002] No bp log location saved, using default.
>
> [000:003] Cpu: 6.60.3, x4, 2400Mhz, 3711MB
>
> [000:003] Computer model: Not available
>
> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f67a13dd2a1, pid=12562, tid=140085593491200
>
> JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_91-b02) (build 1.7.0_91-
>   b02)
>
> Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.91-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>
> Derivative: IcedTea 2.6.3
>
> Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, package 7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
>
> Problematic frame:
>
> C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
>
> Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>
> /home/prabhanjan/hs_err_pid12562.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
>
> instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
>
> http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
>
> The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>    See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
thank you for your help in advance